# In cypress clicking on the button does not load the following page

Tags: cypress

```
  cy.get('article button[class*="primary"]').then($button => {
        if ($button.is(':visible')) {
            cy.wrap($button).click({force:true})
        }
    })
```

when executing these commands, it finds the button, but nothing happens.

I tried many ways but I can't find a solution
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP6bf.png)

Comment: I cannot see the error thrown by cypress. Can you add that?

Comment: `Error: Invalid URL: undefined
    at index.ts:38:11
    at f (runtime.js:63:40)
    at Generator._invoke (runtime.js:294:22)
    at Generator.next (runtime.js:119:21)
    at n (asyncToGenerator.js:3:20)
    at s (asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
    at nrWrapper (gilded-)`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you will use {force:true} to click you can just use

```
cy.get('article button[class*="primary"]').click({force:true})
```

this should work, if not please let me know.

Best regards,
Caíque Coelho

Comment: yes, I tried this but it didn't work either

Comment: Maybe your problem isn't clicking on the button, because the error message has nothing to do with this interaction. What is the content in the index.ts file at line 38? Also, can you send us the debug execution video of this test, please?